# JavaScript presses Dead key twice, passes input validation allowing only numbers to be entered

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, onkeydown

Good morning everyone, I have the following function that validates that only numerical characters can be entered in a text input. The problem is that if I press the Dead key twice, '´ is entered in the text input.

```
input_numeric.onkeydown = numericKeyboard;
function numericKeyboard(e) {
  if (e.key != 0 && e.key != 1 && e.key != 2 && e.key != 3 && e.key != 4 && e.key != 5 && e.key != 6 && e.key != 7 && e.key != 8 && e.key != 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Please someone can help me solve my problem.

Comment: Do you want to handle only the `paste` event?

Comment: Listen `input` event, and remove the unwanted characters from the value.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of preventing default, just don't allow any of the not allowed input

Using the input event will handle typing and pasting

```js
const input_numeric = document.getElementById("numeric");
const notallowed = /[^0-9\.\-\+]/g // add e if you need exponent
const allow = (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const text = tgt.value;
  tgt.value = text.replace(notallowed,"");
};
input_numeric.addEventListener("input", allow);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numeric" />

or just

<input type="number" /> which however will allow .e for example due to numbers like 2.04e10
```

If you insist on preventDefault, we can try this. Note that the input event cannot use preventDefault since it triggers after input

```js
const checkInput = (e,pasting) => {
  let text;
  if (pasting) {
    const clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    text = clipboardData.getData('Text');
  } 
  else text = e.key;

  if (/[^0-9]/.test(text)) {
    console.log(`${pasting ? 'Pasting' : 'Input'} is prevented because it contains a non-numeric character.`);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}; 
const field = document.getElementById('numeric');
field.addEventListener('paste', (e) => checkInput(e,true));
field.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  checkInput(e, false);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numeric" />
```

Comment: Why won't preventing default work?